# Resonance in wave equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, eigenfunctions

I have solved the non-homogenous equation by the method of eigenfunction expansion
$$u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx}=F(x)\sin(\omega t)$$
$$0<x<L, t>0$$
$$u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0$$
$$u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$$
and got the following solution:
$$u(x,t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2L\sin(\omega t)\int\limits_0^L F(x)sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) dx}{(cn\pi)^2-(L\omega)^2}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$

Now I need to find the resonant solution by taking the limit of $u(x,t)$ as $\omega\to c k\pi/L$:
$$\lim\limits_{\omega\to \frac{ck\pi}{L}} u(x,t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2L\sin(\frac{ck\pi}{L} t)\int\limits_0^L F(x)sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx}{(cn\pi)^2-({ck\pi})^2}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$

Can please someone let me know what is it that I'm not doing right here? Would appreciate some help.

Comment: What is $k$?  And $\omega$ is an arbitrary constant?  If it is, the first solution doesn't make sense for certain $\omega$.  Unless you're claiming that's a solution when $\omega$ isn't equal to $ck\pi/L$ for some positive integer $k$.

Comment: @mathematician You're correct, $\omega \ne ck\pi/L$,  and $k$ is a positive integer. Though, honestly, I don't see why it wouldn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: The first equation would have a 0 in the denominator for $n=\omega L /(c\pi)$.

Comment: @mathematician Oh, I see. Of course, in this sense - yes.

Comment: @mathematician So can you please help with the resonance part?

Comment: Something is weird with your first solution, it is constant in $x$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've now made the correction.

Comment: The term with $n=k$ is blowing up for almost all $x, t$ as $\omega\rightarrow ck\pi/L$.  It doesn't look like this approach works, unless there's a mistake in your first solution.